# chrome extension storage.get can't set default

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which stores user config in chrome.storage.sync. For new users, I want to provide a default config, so I'm using chrome.storage.sync.get with default values, like shown in the code below.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to set anything, as when I later check it, nothing is in storage. What am I doing wrong?

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
        console.log("oninstalled called");
        const defaultConfig = {
            hideFirms: true,
            searchRegular: true,
            feedbackRange: [0, 100],
            blacklist: [],
        };
        // only provide default values if there is no config already in the storage...
        chrome.storage.sync.get({ "config": defaultConfig}, response => {
            console.log("response from getting/setting: ", response);

            chrome.storage.sync.get("config", r => { 
                console.log("while respin pure getter is: ", r);
            });
            chrome.storage.sync.get(null, r => { 
                console.log("and whole storage contents are: ", r);
            });
        });
    });
```

The console.log result I'm getting in the background page:
[image]

As you can see, the first console.log shows the defaultConfig, the other 2 calls return an empty object.

Comment: The default value isn't written to the storage, it's only returned into your callback. That's how it works.

Comment: @wOxxOm that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.